# QLineEdit textChanged signal not called

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I want to connect a textChanged signal to a QLineEdit, but it never gets called:

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Dialog();
    virtual ~Dialog();
    QLineEdit *nameEdit;

public slot:
    void nameChanged(const QString &);
};
```

.c file:

```
Dialog::Dialog()
{

    nameEdit=new QLineEdit;
    connect(nameEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(nameChanged(const QString &)));
    ...
}

void Dialog::nameChanged(const QString & txt)
{
// NEVER CALLED
}
```

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: Does it give a debug message when it starts that signal/slot are not available? Look in your console/terminal.

Comment: It's actually part of a maya plugin I am writing, so no access to Qt console.

Comment: Is your nameChanged() function marked as a slot?

Comment: Why is `nameChanged` under signals? It should be a slot.

Comment: @LaurentCrivello Dear lord... why did you change `nameChanged()` to a signal?????????????????????????? It was right when it was a public slot!

Comment: Ok, changed back to public slot (saw the signals: on a web site). But still does not work.

Comment: Btw, `nameEdit=new QLineEdit( ---> this <--- );`

Comment: @DmitrySazonov No. This is not absolutely the right thing to do. It depends on your design model. For example, adding a widget to a layout takes care of this parenting issue. Actually, if you're just `this`ing every widget you create, you could easily cause a segfault on the program exit.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist layouts it's just another way to manage widgets relations. And there are no possible segfaults. Only if you are doing something wrong (for example: delete widget during slot processing, but it may be handleled with `deleteLater` mehod, or making widgets on stack instead of heap). You may read about memory management in Qt to get more info.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov You're telling a beginner to `this` a `QLineEdit` (which is normally in a layout)... this is very bad advice! When I used to `this` everything like you're recommending here, I used to have crashes (segfault) on exit. I understand Qt memory management quite well, and without `this`ing anything, valgrind never gives me memory-leak issues on widgets. Such bold advice is dangerous without explaining in detail why it may be dangerous. You're making it sound necessary while it's not. I hope you understand why this advice is more harmful than useful.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist cound you be more specific about segfauls? Please, provide an SSCCE. If you will read a question, you will see next line: `nameEdit=new QLineEdit;`. There `QLineEdit` will be created as a separate window and will not be destroyed even on exit. So, my proposal is correct fix, without immersion in details. Question is not about layouts.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Sorry I can't provide examples, but I hope my explanation is clear. The reason it's wrong to recommend to `this` that `QLineEdit` without knowing the context (like you said with separate window, which may not be true cuz this is almost an MCVE) is one would ruin the hierarchy of destruction that Qt is going to do for you. If you have widgets in widgets in widgets (through layouts, or otherwise), then inserting widgets will automatically create parents for you. Enforcing a parent like you're recommending means you're telling Qt "I know what I'm doing", while the beginner may not.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist is is a common Qt practice to specify parent widgets when you programmaticaly create children. When you retarget a widget to layout or other widget - parent/child object tree will be reordered automatically by Qt. Ok, anyway it's too chatty discussion and not related to the original question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The old style usually writes a debug message in the console/terminal if something is wrong with the connection. Since you don't have a console, I highly recommend that you immediately stop using the *old* style of signals and slots, and use the new form which uses modern function binding:

```
connect(nameEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &Dialog::nameChanged);
```

Try this, and see if it compiles. If it doesn't, it would mean that one of the signals/slots is overloaded, and in that case you'll need to statically cast to the overload you want to connect to. Another reason for a compilation error is that your connections are not compatible.

Advantages:

1. Once this compiles, it works
2. It's resolved at compile time, not run-time, so it's faster
3. It doesn't use strings to resolve function names

PS: For full disclosure, the guy had that `nameChanged()` as a public slot (check his edit), and he changed it to a signal... no idea what's going on there.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Dialog();
    virtual ~Dialog();
    QLineEdit *nameEdit;

signals:
    void nameChanged(const QString &);
};
```

You want to use **nameChanged()** as a **slot** and not a **signal**

so the correct way is :

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Dialog();
    virtual ~Dialog();
    QLineEdit *nameEdit;

public slots:
    void nameChanged(const QString &);
};
```

Comment: The slot nameChanged could be overloaded so u need to cast the slot and you can skip 'public' in public slots as it was immediately under 'public' block.